# Eventbrite.php Error

Tags: php, eventbrite

I am working with this api for Eventbrite https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php

It pulls the events in ok but when there are know events posted it gives me an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No events found for this user.' in /home/davidhender/glasgowcitymission.davidhendersondesign.com/news-events/Eventbrite.php:109 Stack trace: #0 /home/davidhender/glasgowcitymission.davidhendersondesign.com/news-events/events/eventbrite.php(17): Eventbrite->__call('user_list_event...', Array) #1 /home/davidhender/glasgowcitymission.davidhendersondesign.com/news-events/events/eventbrite.php(17): Eventbrite->user_list_events() #2 {main} thrown in /home/davidhender/glasgowcitymission.davidhendersondesign.com/news-events/Eventbrite.php on line 109

```
    <?php
// load the API Client library
include "../Eventbrite.php"; 

// Initialize the API client
//  Eventbrite API / Application key (REQUIRED)
//   http://www.eventbrite.com/api/key/
//  Eventbrite user_key (OPTIONAL, only needed for reading/writing private user data)
//   http://www.eventbrite.com/userkeyapi
$authentication_tokens = array('app_key'  => 'UHH2XQAMZXTTZM526G',
                               'user_key' => '139627418395393246769');
$eb_client = new Eventbrite( $authentication_tokens );

// For more information about the features that are available through the Eventbrite API, see http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/
$events = $eb_client->user_list_events();

//mark-up the list of events that were requested 
// render in html - ?>
<style type="text/css">
.eb_event_list_item{
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.eb_event_list_title{
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.eb_event_list_date{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.eb_event_list_time{
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
}
.eb_event_list_location{
  position: absolute;
  left: 520px;
}
</style>

<h1>My Event List:</h1>
<?= Eventbrite::eventList( $events, 'eventListRow'); ?>
```

Comment: use `try... catch` to catch a exception, like `<?php try { echo Eventbrite::eventList( $events, 'eventListRow'); } catch(Exception $e) { echo 'No events found for this user.'; } ?>`

Comment: Thanks but it's still giving me the same error

Comment: Sorry, i've used the `try` on wrong code block, look my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php 
try {
    $events = $eb_client->user_list_events();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // Be sure to plan for potential error cases 
    // so that your application can respond appropriately
    $events = array();
}
?>
```

to echoes the event list

```
<?= Eventbrite::eventList( $events, 'eventListRow'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but still no luck with this.

Comment: its still giving the same error:http://glasgowcitymission.davidhendersondesign.com/news-events/events/eventbrite.php

Comment: @user3612484 which is the content of line 17?

Comment: $events = $eb_client->user_list_events();

Comment: and you placed this line inside the `try` block?